# Erlang escript launching application with start parameters

Tags: erlang, escript

Currently my Erlang application is started within an escript (TCP server) and all works fine since it uses the default port I provided. Now I want to pass the port via the escript to the application but I have no idea how. (*The app runs a supervisor*)

**script.escript**

```
!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- erlang -*-

-export([main/1]).

main([UDPort, TCPort]) ->
   U = list_to_integer(UDPort),
   T = list_to_integer(TCPort),

    app:start(), %% Want to pass T into the startup.
  receive
    _ -> ok
  end;

...
```

**app.erl**

```
-module(app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/0, start/2, stop/0, stop/1]).

-define(PORT, 4300).

start () -> application:start(?MODULE). %% This is called by the escript.
stop () -> application:stop(?MODULE).

start (_StartType, _StartArgs) -> supervisor:start(?PORT).
stop (_State) -> ok.
```

*I'm honestly not sure if this is possible with using application but I thought it best to just ask.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way is to start things from whatever shell just calling

```
erl -run foo
```

But you can also do

```
erl -appname key value
```

to set an environment value and then

```
application:get_env(appname, key)
```

to get the value you are looking for.

That said...

I like to have service applications be things that don't have to shut down to be (re)configured. I usually include some message protocol like `{config, Aspect, Setting}` or similar that can alter the basic state of a service on the fly. Because I often do this I usually just wind up having whatever script starts up the application also send a configuration message to it.

So with this in mind, consider this rough conceptual example:

```
!/usr/bin/env escript
%% -*- erlang -*-

-export([main/1]).

main([UDPort, TCPort]) ->
    U = list_to_integer(UDPort),
    T = list_to_integer(TCPort),
    ok = case whereis(app) of
        undefined ->  app:start();
        _Pid      ->  ok
    end,
    ok = set_ports(U, T).

%% Just an illustration.
%% Making this a synchronous gen_server/gen_fsm call is way better.
set_ports(U, T) ->
    app ! {config, listen, {tcp, T}},
    app ! {config, listen, {udp, U}},
    ok.
```

Now not only is the startup script a startup script, it is also a config script. The point isn't to have a startup script, it is to have a service running on the ports you designated. This isn't a conceptual fit for all tools, of course, but it should give you some ideas. There is also the practice of putting a config file somewhere the application knows to look and just reading terms from it, among other techniques (like including ports in the application specification, etc.).

**Edit**

I just realized you are doing this in an escript which will spawn a new node every time you call it. To make the technique above work properly you would need to make the escript name a node for the service to run on, and locate it if it already exists.